# Unselect Address Bar in Firefox

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I know that I can jump *to* the address bar (aka Location bar) with `Ctrl - L`. But once I'm there, I can't figure out how to go back to "normal mode", i.e. where `Space` / `Shift - Space` go page up/down etc.

Comment: How about a few `Tabs`?

Comment: The focus will cycle around the window by hitting Tab.  Shift-Tab will go backwards in the same list.

Comment: I just counted. For me, that's seven `Tab`s. But it depends on the number of search engines configured. There must be sth better...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using F6. This toggles the focus on the address bar.